# How to pass environment variables in gitlab dynamically?

Tags: variables, automation, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am working on database deployment using gitlab CICD. Now there are two databases e.g. ABC and XYZ. One team is working on DB ABC and we are working on DB XYZ. Now the logic is same but if we need to pass DB name according to the team in gitlab pipeline, Whats the process fotr that ? for example if team 1 is working they will select DB ABC and all changes will be reflected on ABC and same for the other. I have already set up variables in gitlab-ci.yml but the task is manual as one team has to overwrite name of DB of other team and when it merges to master it chanhges the variable name everytime which is hard to manage .

```
    variables:
  DB_NAME_dev: DEMO_DB
  DB_NAME_qa: DEMO_DB
  DB_NAME_prod: DEMO_DB
```

Now if team 2 wants to work on their pipeline they have to change the value of DB_NAME_dev to their database which is a manual task. Is there a smart way to select DB name and the pipeline runs only for that database rather than manually editing the DB name ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tricky interaction between how Gitlab evaluates its own `variables` and the regular environment variables in your shell. Gitlab ignores all your environment variables when doing its evaluation. So any reference to them will be empty in the `variables` section and therefore in the `script` section. This kind of makes sense due to the fact that the pipelines and everything have to be set up before any of the runners actually picks up the job and gets a shell with an environment.

However, you can tell Gitlab you don't want the variable evaluated until the script actually runs, using a special syntax.

In your `.profile`:

```bash
export CI_DB_NAME=DEMO_DB_xyz
```

In your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
#Note the double $$ instead of single $
dev-job:
  variables:
    - DB_TO_TEST: $${CI_DB_NAME}
  script:
    - ./run_my_tests ${DB_TO_TEST}  # Single $ is OK here because it runs in the shell
```

This is noted very briefly here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-cicd-variables-in-other-variables

Since you're now relying on the user's environment, you might want to check in your script that it's defined and non-empty, and fail otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass variables in GitLab?
An alternative is to use Gitlab Variables. Go to your project page, Settings tab -> CI/CD, find Variables and click on the Expand button. Here you can define variable names and values, which will be automatically passed into the gitlab pipelines, and are available as environment variables there.

Comment: Yes , I know this . but we want to keep a uniform structure. For example the team ABC wants to deploy db named db_ABC so they will make the variable DB_NAME_dev as db_ABC and similarly db_XYZ by team XYZ . but when this is merged into master it will change the varaible value in master accordingly and this is a manual process. If one team forgets to change the DB name then it will impact other team's work. So we want to have a uniform process so that DB name is asked during trigger and then the team needs to enter their DB name accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the git branch method. Let's say the 'ABC' and 'XYZ' team pushes their code to specific branches (eg. branch starting with 'abc' or 'xyz'). For those, you need to export variables in `before_script` with `only` parameter.

Create branch-specific jobs in your CI file:

```
abc-dev-job:
  before_script:
    - export DB_NAME_dev: $DEMO_DB_abc
    - export DB_NAME_qa: $DEMO_DB_abc
    - export DB_NAME_prod: $DEMO_DB_abc
  only:
    - /^abc/.*$/@gitlab-org/gitlab

xyz-dev-job:
  before_script:
    - export DB_NAME_dev: $DEMO_DB_xyz
    - export DB_NAME_qa: $DEMO_DB_xyz
    - export DB_NAME_prod: $DEMO_DB_xyz
  only:
    - /^xyz/.*$/@gitlab-org/gitlab
```

This pipeline will only run when Team 'XYZ' or 'ABC' pushes their code to their team-specific branches which might start with the prefix `xyz` or `abc` (eg. xyz-dev, xyz/dev, abc-dev, etc.)
And it will use variables accordingly.
Note: you need to define variables in CI/CD settings.
Thank you!

Comment: The problem is there is no pattern of branching.Any developer could create their branch name of their choice.  For example the team ABC wants to deploy db named db_ABC so they will make the variable DB_NAME_dev as db_ABC and similarly db_XYZ by team XYZ . but when this is merged into master it will change the varaible value in master accordingly and this is a manual process. If one team forgets to change the DB name then it will impact other team's work. So we want to have a uniform process so that DB name is asked during trigger and then the team needs to enter their DB name accordingly

Comment: OK, I don't know how exactly can we solve this problem, but using branching patterns like `abc-feature/smsnotification`, `xyz-fix/contentfilesize`, or similar might be a good approach also... And I'm very curious to find out a more feasible approach for such types of issues.